# poco class custom name

Tags: entity-framework-4

Is there a way to a coded class called "Pessoa" decorate some atttribute to be referenced with a conceptual class named as "Person" that is in a conceptual model ? I'm mean:

```
[Table("Person")] // or something like that
public class Pessoa
```

I tried

```
[EdmEntityTypeAttribute(Name = "Person")]
```

but no success....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is MS answer:

> Currently, Entity Framework doesn't
>   support custom mapping between Object
>   and Conceptual types (names should
>   match). However, we will be
>   considering this feature for future
>   releases.
>
> Thanks,
>
> Kavitha Jonnakuti
>
> Entity Framework test team